# Calculating size of Text Rectangle area based on map zoomScale

Tags: ios

I have custom mapOverlayView that display a text on a map using this code:

```
- (void)drawMapRect:(MKMapRect)mapRect
          zoomScale:(MKZoomScale)zoomScale
          inContext:(CGContextRef)ctx
{
       [super drawMapRect:mapRect zoomScale:zoomScale inContext:ctx];
        NSString *t=text2display;
      CGPoint point = CGPointMake(0,30);
        CGFloat fontSize = (3 * MKRoadWidthAtZoomScale(zoomScale)); 

        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:fontSize];

        // Draw outlined text.
        CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(ctx, kCGTextStroke);
        // Make the thickness of the outline a function of the font size in use.
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, fontSize/18);
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(ctx, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);
        [t drawAtPoint:point withFont:font];
        CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
       UIGraphicsPopContext();
```

I have also a corresponding mapOverlay that create the rectangle area of the text:

```
- (MKMapRect)boundingMapRect
{

MKMapRect bounds = MKMapRectMake(upperLeft.x, upperLeft.y-Z , 2000, 2000);

    return bounds;
}
```

I need the bottom line of text to always stay at same level. Thus, I need to change the value of Z in the above code depending on the size of text to be drawn.

The size of text depends on **zoomScale** of the map. **Is there away to know the zoom scale of the map?** so that I could calculate the size of the text.